# compile android project to apk using php

Tags: php, android, eclipse, apk

i have android project created by eclipse i need to compile it to android apk

how can i do it using php ?

also how can i use custom keystore ?

some website do this using .net but can i do this using php ?

or i can run some script using root access to do this and create android apk ?

i cant find something like this in this website

```
http://www.phpforandroid.net/doku.php
```

thanks everyone :)

sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Look up compiling android project from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you must be running Android ant. Then, you must run:

```
ant release
```

This will compile the APK, but if you also want to sign it, run:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore pathtokeystore.keystore pathtounsignedapp.apk alias_name
```

It will require passwords for the keystore and key. The unsigned apk will be signed in place, and you can just return the apk.

Comment: Navigate (in terminal) where ant is, and then run ./ant. Same deal with jarsigner.

Comment: i get this error Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!

Comment: Do you know how to use ant?

Comment: Because you must have build.xml and it has to contain some information about your SDK.

Comment: thank you i have other question can i change the package name using command ?

Comment: Assuming you are using Linux, you could use `mv old_name new_name`.